# How to see the reject/re-direct reason for rows in SSIS? (row-level)

Tags: ssis, validation

I use SSDT (aka SSIS or BIDS 2012 or Visual Studio 2010): I have a data conversion step and some of my rows are rejected (i.e. redirected to a reject text file). Everything is great and it seems like the rejects were valid, HOWEVER, how can I see the reason for the rejection? I do not have time to go manually validate the process every time. I have over 100 columns coming in, and I need to know which one is giving me trouble on a consistent basis. "Progress" tab just shows the control flow progress and does not provide row-level information

Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Data Conversion transformation adds ErrorCode and ErrorColumn (both int) to the plipeline. You can use Script Component to translate ErrorCode (First add ScriptErrDesc to Output Columns in editor):

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Row.ScriptErrDesc = this.ComponentMetaData.GetErrorDescription(Row.ErrorCode);
}
```

I was unable to retrieve the column names yet, but I think you just need to play around with ComponentMetaData.